# Python GEKKO: optimizing performance of nonlinear optimization

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I'm using `GEKKO‍` for solving a nonlinear programming problem. My goal is to compare the `GEKKO‍` performance with an alternative, and so I want to make sure that I'm getting from `GEKKO‍` the best it can offer.

There are *n* binary variables, each of them is assigned a weight, each of the weights is a number from the interval *[0, 1]* (i.e., a rational number *w* satisfying *0<= w <= 1*). Each of the constraints is linear. The objective function is non-linear: it is the product of weights of the non-zero variables, and the goal is to maximize the product.

I started with specifying the objective function as

```
m.Obj(-np.prod([1 - variables[i] + weights[i] * variables[i] for i in range(len(variables))]))
```

but then I would bump into `APM model error: string > 15000  characters`. So I switched to auxiliary variables using the `if3` function as

```
aux_variables = [m.if3(variables[i], weights[i], 1) for i in range(len(variables))]
m.Obj(-np.prod(aux_variables))
```

The only global parameters that I'm setting manually are in the following code.

```
# initialize model

m = GEKKO(remote=False)


# set global variables

m.options.SOLVER = 1 # APOPT solver
# "APOPT is an MINLP solver"
# "APOPT is also the only solver that handles Mixed Integer problems."

m.options.IMODE = 3 # steady state optimization

m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']

# initialize variables
variables = m.Array(m.Var, (number_of_vars), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)

# set initial values
for var in variables:
    var.value = 1
```

**Question:**

what more, if anything, can I do, in terms of global parameters and formulation of the objective function, to optimize the `GEKKO‍`'s performance for this particular problem?

At the same time, I would love `GEKKO‍` to produce decent results.

Comment: What range can the weight be in your problem?

Comment: Each of the weights is a constant from the interval [0, 1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to reformulate your problem for increased speed is to use Intermediate variables.

**Original (0.0325 sec with # Var=5)**

```py
m.Obj(-np.prod([1 - variables[i] + weights[i] * variables[i] \
      for i in range(len(variables))]))
```

**Modified (0.0156 sec with # Var=5)**

```py
ival = [m.Intermediate(1 - variables[i] + weights[i] * variables[i]) \
                       for i in range(len(variables))]
m.Obj(-np.prod(ival))
```

This should also help you avoid the problem with string length, unless you have `number_of_vars` that is very large. It seems that the optimal solution will always be `variables[i]=1` when `weights[i]=1` and `variables[i]=0` when `weights[i]=0`. With `np.prod` this means that the entire objective function is zero is any one of the product terms are zero. Would it help to set the individual product values equal to `1` instead of using the objective function to find the values? One thing that helps APOPT find a correct solution is to use something like `1.1` in your intermediate declaration instead of `1.0`. So that when you are maximizing, it tries to avoid `0.1` values in favor of finding a solution that gives `1.1`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
number_of_vars = 5
weights = [0,1,0,1,0]
m.options.IMODE = 3
variables = m.Array(m.Var, (number_of_vars), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
for var in variables:
    var.value = 1
ival = [m.Intermediate(1.1 - variables[i] + weights[i] * variables[i]) \
                       for i in range(len(variables))]
# objective function
m.Obj(-np.prod(ival))
# integer solution with APOPT
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']
m.solve()
print(variables)
```

It is also much easier for a solver to find a solution to a summation such as `m.sum()` and it gives the same `variables` solution as the `np.prod()` option.

```py
# objective function
m.Obj(-m.sum(ival))
```

You could add a post-process line to recover product objective function that will be either `0` or `1`.

The `if3` function isn't a good option for your application because the switching condition is at 0 and slight numerical variations will cause unreliable results. The solver considers `0` to `0.05` and `0.95` to `1` to be integer solutions according to the option `minlp_integer_tol=0.05`. This is an option that allows integer solutions to be accepted when they are close enough to an integer value. If the `variables[i]` value is `0.01` then the `if3` function will chose the `True` option when it should select the `False` option. You could still use the `if3` function if you made the switch point between the binary values such as `m.if3(variables[i]-0.5, weights[i], 1)`. However, there are easier ways to solve your problem than using the `if3` function.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer, in particular for the explanations on `if3`.

It seems that I wasn't clear in my original post: the weights are rational numbers between 0 and 1 (including, but NOT limited to, 0 and 1). Thus, I cannot use the summation instead of the product.

The number of variables is up to ~2500.

I will do some reading about the usage of intermediate variables and see what happens when they are employed here.

Comment: Switching to intermediate variables helped a bit with the limit on the string length and the speed, as well as the accuracy of the results, as compared with the results when using `if3`. The results returned are still awfully far from the optimal ones, but it seems that nothing can be done about it, as the function to be optimized is highly complex.